# Adapting xCode 8 and ios 10 from xCode 7

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am adapting official xCode 8 and I got some issue. 
One is push notification. If I don't turn on in xCode 8, I can't even register to get apns token. In xCode 7, it is okay.

[image]

After that, I have to put permission for camera, photo library access, etc. If I don't, app crash immediately like this. When I use xCode 7, it doesn't happen.

> 2016-09-20 19:36:27.026615 AppName[20437:4432867] [access] This app
>   has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data
>   without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSContactsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

But, at this moment, I am quite reluctant to use xCode 8 because I gonna have to upload to App Store. And many unexpected thing can happen (app just crash immediately, app doesn't receive notification.).

Is there anything to take note for adapting xCode 8? I am trying to find but I don't see.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. If you access contacts, you must have an NSContactsUsageDescription in iOS 9 too. If you have push notifications, you must get entitlements in iOS 9. So what's new here?

Comment: In xcode 7, I don't put permission description in info.plist. App doesn't crash and can run smoothly. But if I compile with xCode 8, app show error message like that. 

It is same for push notification also. I don't need that one to turn on in xCode 7.

Comment: Well, then what you were doing "in xcode 7" was wrong. Unless you were not using contacts framework.  But in that case this would have nothing to do with the Xcode version.